# Unable to get output from Classes in Python

Tags: python, class, output

[Code that I am using]
I am trying to learn classes in Python and tried to run my first program. I am unable to get an outcome from the program. After running the program, I just get a RESTART C:/Users..... message.

```
#Class example

class Person:
    '''
    The class person describes a person
    '''
    count =0 # class variable that keeps a count of Person instances
    def __init__(self, name, DOB, address): # Constructor i.e. initializer
        self.name=name
        self.DOB=DOB
        self.address=address
        Person.count+=1    # Increase person count by 1 for every instance created

def getName(self):
    '''
    Objective: Retrieve the name of the person
    Input: Self (Implicit Parameter), object of type Person
    Output: Return Value is name-string
    '''
    return self.name

def getDOB(self):
    return self.DOB

def getAddress(self):
    return self.address

def setName (self, name):
    self.name=name

def setDOB(self, DOB):
    self.DOB=DOB

def setAddress(self, address):
    self.address=address

def getCount (self):
    return Person.count

def __str__(self):
    '''
    Objective: Return string representation of object of type Person
    Input: Self (implicit Parameter), object of type Person
    Return: String
    '''
    return 'Name: '+self.name+'DOB: '+self.DOB+'Address: '+self.address


p1= Person('Dave', '24-10-1998', 'NJ, USA')
```

Comment: Can you please provide the entire error message / output that you get? It is worth noting that your code does not have any outputs - you create a person object, however you do not output any details relating to that object. It would also be greatly appreciated if you could put your code in a code block, to make it legible.

Comment: What outcome are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting the output>  Name: Dave,  DOB: 24-10-1998, Address: NJ, USA . I hope that the return statement that I have in def __str__(self) is enough t get this output. Or do I need to use any other statement to get the output?

Comment: @Oliver. R> Thanks for your input. Actually, I am not getting any error. The program runs error free. It is just that I am not getting the Name, DOB and Address as outputs for p1. Do I need to specifically provide an output statement?

Answer (score 0):

(assuming you indented your code  properly)you need to call the methods for the person object.
suppose you want to output the name of the person, you can use the method you defined as follows:

```
print(p1.getName())
```

however you can do this without the method like:

```
print(p1.name)
```

you can now output other values similarly.

if you want the entire information(using `__str__`), you can do:

```
print(str(p1))
```

here you **do not** need `p1.__str__` as its a magic/dunder method.

Comment: Thanks! Where exactly do I need to insert this command? In the def__init__ block?

Comment: if you want to output every time you cerate an object, put `print('Name: '+self.name+'DOB: '+self.DOB+'Address: '+self.address)` at the end of innit, after you define the variables. if you want to get output as you will, you can do the above **after** you create the object.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods(functions in a class) - do not appear to be indented...

We would expect the class to look like

```
class Person:
    def setName (self, name):
        self.name=name

    def setDOB(self, DOB):
        self.DOB=DOB

   def setAddress(self, address):
        self.address=address

   def getCount (self):
        return Person.count
```

Then

```
p1= Person('Dave', '24-10-1998', 'NJ, USA')
print(str(p1))
```

Looks fine

Comment: Thanks for your input! I had initially indented the class functions and tried to run the code. However, I kept getting the error "unexpected indentation". I settled for the posted version of code after some trial and error. Now, I do not get the indentation error.

Comment: If you get errors like this (which are common in python) have a look at either "black" or "white" -or "autopep8" ... these utils will reformat your code, and either fix,or at least show you where your indentation issues are.